# Why are changes to DNS not published as a log?

Tags: domain-name-system

I was wondering why it is so difficult to keep up to date with DNS and why the various servers don't simply stream a log of updates to a public file server.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Because DNS is a pull protocol, not a push protocol. Everyone doesn't need to know every `subdomain.example.com.`.

Comment: It would be an immense amount of data, and not all DNS records are intended to be public.

Comment: I don't buy the amount of data argument. That seems like it could be solvable. But I understand there is a soft expectation of secrecy.

Comment: @Alper Certificate transparency logs are already hundreds of gigabytes - Google's contains over five million records in the short time it's been running - and SSL certs are probably a couple orders of magnitude less common than DNS changes are.

Comment: DNS _was_ and _is_ the solution to the immense amount of data. It was identified as a serious problem in the early 1980s! (RFC 882). For a history of the way things used to be done, see RFC 1034 section 2.1.

Comment: Can you clarify what you think is difficult about the way the DNS protocol works?

Comment: "why the various servers don't simply stream a log of updates to a public file server."  because one of the important property of the DNS is to be decentralized and hierarchical. You loose all of that if you decide to elect one public file server where everyone has to send information. And how do you authenticate each sender?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I may have been unclear, each DNS server could elect to stream its change stream somewhere. No centralisation required.

Comment: Then what do you gain? Imagine each nameserver out there sends its data to its own specific unique log stream endpoint. You have now as name servers to contact as before...

Answer (score 5):

Maintaining a centralized list/table/database of host names became unwieldy and untenable and is why the (decentralized) DNS system was created in the first place.

What's inherently wrong with the current implementation of DNS as you see it? What problem actually needs solving? How would you solve it?

This question may get closed, but I'm sincerely interested in hearing your take.

Comment: Echoing joeqwerty's comment because I've never had an issue keeping stuff up to date, all it takes is knowing how things work, what needs to change, when it needs to change, and planning it all out.  If someone else out there has issues resolving my stuff after a change, it is because their DNS source isn't honoring TTLs, etc.

Comment: There are lots of people interested in DNS changes and that is where a bunch of weird solutions such as passivedns come in. I think all of that could be fixed pretty easily if DNS updates were published to one (or more) change stream(s).

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you mean by "lots of people interested in DNS changes"?

Comment: @DougDeden At least in cybersecurity, this is a thing that people look at, say: https://dns-database-download.whoisxmlapi.com

Comment: So someone decided to gather a bunch of historical data. I still don't understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Alper Is what you're actually asking for essentially an audit log? But why public?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I mean if it were not public it would defeat a large part of the point. DNS is already a public system and privacy is mostly safeguarded by inconvenience and rate limiting?

Comment: @Alper Many of the questions center around what the purpose is, as it appears to be of no relevance to actual operation of the system but rather something else. That making this log private would "defeat the point" doesn't really clarify anything when the point was never explained in the first place.